# How to convert time without time zone to timestamp without time zone in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, cast, heroku, rails

I received this error when trying to alter a column of type `time` to type `timestamp`:

```
PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type time without time zone to timestamp without time zone
```

It's not important to me how the existing times are converted, but I do need this column to be changed. How can I force this or cast this?

This is the SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE "students" ALTER COLUMN "time_since_missing_schedule_notification" TYPE timestamp USING CAST(time_since_missing_schedule_notification AS timestamp)
```

I'm using Rails/ActiveRecord and this was the Ruby code that generated the above SQL statement:

```
change_column :students, :time_since_missing_schedule_notification, 'timestamp USING CAST(time_since_missing_schedule_notification AS timestamp without time zone)'
```

When I connect to Heroku's PostgreSQL server, I get these versions:

```
psql (9.3.1, server 9.2.7)
```

Comment: Do you just want to convert a value or alter the data type of the column in the table?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter alter the data type, you answered it perfectly below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since time does not have a `date` component you need to provide a date. You can just add `date` and `time` values in the `ALTER TABLE` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE students ALTER COLUMN time_since_missing_schedule_notification
 TYPE timestamp USING ('2000-1-1'::date + time_since_missing_schedule_notification)
```